# How to setup Raylib for game development in C on macOS?

Tags: c, linker-errors, setup-project, raylib

I am a complete beginner with programming in C and in order to motivate myself to spend more time programming in C, I would like to try game programming. Looked around and discovered Raylib which is a C/C++ game framework.

However, the documentation and all tutorials online I can find are using an installer or IDE package or GIT to install Raylib. This is not how I would like to do it.
I would like to "simply" just include Raylib in my C project and that's it, but I can't get it working this way, I'm getting linker errors on macOS 12.1.

I am using just a plain text editor and terminal, no fancy IDE.
I have downloaded Raylib from itch.io and I have copied the "include" and "lib" folders in to my project folder. Finally, I have created "main.c" in my project folder.

The content of main.c looks like this:

```
#include "include/raylib.h"

int main(void)
{
    // Initialization
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    const int screenWidth = 800;
    const int screenHeight = 450;

    InitWindow(screenWidth, screenHeight, "raylib [core] example - basic window");

    SetTargetFPS(60);               // Set our game to run at 60 frames-per-second
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    // Main game loop
    while (!WindowShouldClose())    // Detect window close button or ESC key
    {
        // Update
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // TODO: Update your variables here
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        // Draw
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        BeginDrawing();

            ClearBackground(RAYWHITE);

            DrawText("Congrats! You created your first window!", 190, 200, 20, LIGHTGRAY);

        EndDrawing();
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    }

    // De-Initialization
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    CloseWindow();        // Close window and OpenGL context
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile it using "make main.c", I get the following linking errors: cc main.c -o main

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_BeginDrawing", referenced from:
      _main in raylib-7a2ee2.o
  "_ClearBackground", referenced from:
      _main in raylib-7a2ee2.o
  "_CloseWindow", referenced from:
      _main in raylib-7a2ee2.o
  "_DrawText", referenced from:
      _main in raylib-7a2ee2.o
  "_EndDrawing", referenced from:
      _main in raylib-7a2ee2.o
  "_InitWindow", referenced from:
      _main in raylib-7a2ee2.o
  "_SetTargetFPS", referenced from:
      _main in raylib-7a2ee2.o
  "_WindowShouldClose", referenced from:
      _main in raylib-7a2ee2.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [raylib] Error 1
```

The folder structure is looks like this:

```
MyProject
-include
--raygui.h
--raylib.h
--rlgl.h
-lib
--libraylib4.0.0.dylib
--libraylib400.dylib
--libraylib.a
--libraylib.dylib
-main.c
```

Could someone please help me explain why do I get the linker errors and share some tips how to solve it?

I would appreciate any help.

Thank you.

Comment: And how do you compile and link this code together? What commands do you use? For figuring out linker errors that part is important

Comment: I simply enter "make main.c"  which output cc main.c -o main

Comment: You will need to tell the linker to which libraries need to be linked to your binary.

Comment: have you tried cmake?